# Error Conflict of libraries. Weblogic. Problems with project libraries

Tags: weblogic, libraries, weblogic12c

I'm having problems with my libraries from my WebService, I need to use my project libs, jaxws..etc.
The error is occurring: weblogic.wsee.databinding.internal.wlsjaxrpc.JaxRpcProvider to com.sun.xml.ws.spi.db.DatabindingProvider.
I'm trying to put in Weblogic.xml, however I'm not sure how to declare the libraries properly. 
Has anyone ever experienced this ?
Thank

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem ?